# PHP MVC Framework Laravel Seems an Error Artisan Serve

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

After creating a project by typing

```
laravel new "first-project"
```

I am writing the below code but is causes an error

```
php artisan serve
```

> Could not open input file: artisan

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ2EL.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `laravel new [project name]` command creates a new project in a subdirectory. You need to cd into that subdirectory.

```
laravel new "first-project"
cd first-project
php artisan serve
```

From the [installation documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation):

> the `laravel new` command will create a fresh Laravel installation in the directory you specify. For instance, `laravel new blog` will create a directory named `blog` containing a fresh Laravel installation with all of Laravel's dependencies already installed

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you would like to make the current working directory the directory that was just created for the project you just created.

Comment: Wow, 2nd place for 3 seconds. :D

Answer (score 0):

"**You need to be inside first-project folder ..**"

You need to first create Laravel project and if you already have one you need to go to this project dir using `cd` command in terminal for example

```
cd first-project
```

Now you will be able to run any artisan commands, for example running

```
php artisan
```

will display you list of available commands.